# Raspberry Pi Rsync

Tags: ssd, raspberrypi, rsync, sd-card

I've run through this guide https://medium.com/xster-tech/move-your-existing-raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-install-from-sd-card-to-usb-ssd-52e99723f07b in order to move Ubuntu from my SD card to my internal SSD.

Everything seems to have worked fine but after cloning https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone and executing `sudo sys-clone sda` it's been running for over 24 hours now. I understand it will be slow due to it swamping the SD card bandwidth but I didn't expect it to take more than a few hours.

It's a large 128GB SD card but as I understand it, rsync doesn't do a byte for byte copy and is file copy based. The SD card had a fresh vanilla install of 64bit PI Ubuntu 20.10 installed. No apps or user data so < 10Gb to copy.

Does this sound like a resonable time to take or should I stop the process and look for an alternative method? Not sure what that would be?

Comment: You can investigate what is happening, if anything, with `iotop`, or `iostat`. Find if a process is running with `top` and look at what files it has open with `lsof -p <pid>`. It might show you where it is in the copying.

Comment: Sorry, bit of a 'nix noob here. I'm assuming you mean to open another terminal instance for this? That won't cause any issues with the running process?

Comment: I tried `sudo iostat` but it's not installed. Is it safe to sudo apt-get in the middle of something like rsync? I originally had Raspian OS installed and that had a utility to copy itself to a USB drive for boot. That was about 6GB install and copied in about 30 mins. I'm convinced this isn't working and also not erroring.

Comment: The USB drive LED is just continually fast steady blinking and not in a pattern that would suggest data being written.

Comment: Note: I dont know `rpi-clone`. Yes, in another terminal. You may need to be root for some command, eg `sudo iotop`. Don't do an `apt-get`. Make sure your `$PATH` includes `/usr/sbin` for example to look for iotop and so on. They may not be in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`.

Comment: I just opened System Monitor. It shows 7.5 GB used on the SD and nothing has been written to the rsync mounted drive. I'm about 95% sure this isn't doing anything useful. What's odd is it's only showing about 25% CPU used yet is running dog slow.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of those things! Will go read. Thanks.

Comment: How would I proceed from here? How do I cancel the rsync without causing any damage to anything else? I was thinking of stopping the process and doing it again but with the verbose flag.

Comment: If you type a `control-Z` in the terminal running the command, that should suspend it.  (`control-C` will stop it, but might just stop the current command, and then the script would go on to do more stuff). You can then reboot and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I've just had a bit of an investigation and it had indeed all gone wrong. It had partitioned the disk and written some data but rebooting to the SSD ended in kernal panic. I tried migrating the bootloader but that didn't work. I'm thinking I should just try to install fresh directly on the SSD since this is a completely new install anyway. Migrating the OS seems above my skills with Linux at the mo :(